# my picked_store on Vega-lite is not functioning. I'm wanting to select filter datapoints by year

Tags: vega-lite, vega

This element of my Vega-lite does not pick up on the desired data. Im wanting the selector to filter data, depending upon the net-zero year

Are my options in the wrong format? Is having a mix of integers and "No Target Selected" invalidating my picked_store?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Equal earth map depicting CO2 emissions per capita. Some countries did not produce any estimates.",
  "title": {
    "text": "Greenhouse Gas Emissions Against CCS Readiness",
    "subtitle": "CO₂ emissions (metric tonne per capita). Source: Our World in Data",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "rgba(58, 59, 60)"
  },
  "height": 500,
  "width": 545,
  "background": null,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jameseconnolly/jameseconnolly.github.io/main/Carbon_Capture_Requirement.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  
  "layer": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "picked": {
          "empty": "none",
          "bind": {
            "Net-zero Target": {
              "input": "select",
              "options": [
                "No Target Selected",
                0,
                2000,
                2030,
                2035,
                2040,
                2045,
                2050,
                2053,
                2060,
                2065,
                2070
              ],
              "name": "Net-zero Target:"
            }
          },
          "type": "single",
          "fields": ["Net-zero Target"]
        },
        "grid": {
          "type": "interval",
          "bind": "scales",
          "on": "[mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "translate": "[mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": "wheel!",
          "resolve": "global"
        }
      },
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "value": "grey",
          "condition": {
            "field": "Cluster",
            "selection": "picked",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": null
          }
        },
        "size": {
          "value": 60,
          "condition": {"value": 120, "selection": "picked"}
        },
        "opacity": {
          "value": 0.4,
          "condition": {"value": 1, "selection": "picked"}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Carbon Capture Requirement",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Carbon Capture and Storage Readiness"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "log_GHG",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Log Greenhouse Gas Emissions (MT CO2e)"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"y": "17", "x": "0"}, {"y": "23", "x": "90"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeDash": [9, 1], "color": "#ff0101"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "x": 540, "align": "right", "y": 20, "size": 25},
      "transform": [{"calculate": "0.1", "as": "R2"}],
      "encoding": {"text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "R2"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to post a full spec

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jameseconnolly/jameseconnolly.github.io/main/chart222.json

Comment: @DavidBacci just attached link above

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the selection is trying to do. The spec makes use of the selection in opacity, size, color and the spec contains lots of errors so it isn't clear to me what it is trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to filter by Net-Zero Target, so that when a year is selected, the filtered data-points on the chart turn from grey to blue.

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following what you want?

[image]

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Equal earth map depicting CO2 emissions per capita. Some countries did not produce any estimates.",
  "title": {
    "text": "Greenhouse Gas Emissions Against CCS Readiness",
    "subtitle": "CO₂ emissions (metric tonne per capita). Source: Our World in Data",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "rgba(58, 59, 60)"
  },
  "height": 500,
  "width": 545,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jameseconnolly/jameseconnolly.github.io/main/Carbon_Capture_Requirement.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "year",
          "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Net-zero Target"]},
          "bind": {
            "input": "select",
            "options": [
           "",
              "2000.0",
              "2030.0",
              "2050.0"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "param": "year",
            "field": "Net-zero Target",
            "type": "nominal"
          },
          "value": "grey"
        },
        "size": {"value": 60},
        "opacity": {"value": 0.4},
        "x": {
          "field": "Carbon Capture Requirement",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Carbon Capture and Storage Readiness"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "log_GHG",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Log Greenhouse Gas Emissions (MT CO2e)"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"y": "17", "x": "0"}, {"y": "23", "x": "90"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeDash": [9, 1], "color": "#ff0101"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "x": 540, "align": "right", "y": 20, "size": 25},
      "transform": [{"calculate": "0.1", "as": "R2"}],
      "encoding": {"text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "R2"}}
    }
  ]
}
```